# Installing CakePHP 2.0 and Getting "Class 'Component' not found" error

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I decided instead of using the migration guide/shell for the upgrade from 1.3 to 2.0 of CakePHP to just go with a vanilla installation of it. For some reason, I'm getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Component' not found in /home/bob_cobb/public_html/mydomain.com/lib/Cake/Controller/Component/SessionComponent.php on line 32
```

When trying to access my website. <strike>I looked to see if SessionComponent.php even exists and it doesn't on my server, nor in the 2.0 repository. Do I need to create this file or something?</strike>  (Edit:  The file exists.)

Comment: What version of PHP are you running?

Comment: @ChuckBurgess it's 5.3. Had to delete my persistent cache and it ended up working.

Comment: @bob_cobb I've encountered a similar error, but I'm having difficulty clearing the cache.  Did you simply delete the files in /app/tmp/cache/persistent folder, or do you need to leave the files and empty them?  Is there another cache location?  I'm getting an error in bootstrap.php, so i can't use cake to clear the cache.

Comment: @AdrianB yeah this was a weird issue. I ended up just saving all of my files locally and deleting/re-installing Cake again. If you're still having issues try hopping onto #cakephp on freenode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its not about the sessioncomponent but the Component class itself:

```
App::uses('Component', 'Controller');
```

This declaration says where to find it. But cake doesnt seem to find it. so it is probably missing.
it should be in `/Cake/Controller/`

Comment: yes, `Component.php` exists as well as `App::uses('Component', 'Controller');` in line 20 of SessionComponent.php. Still getting this error. Going crazy over here.

Comment: cache cleared? cake might have outdated info in /cache/persistent/

Comment: Didn't see this response and just did this. Totally fixed it. Weird. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, [`SessionComponent.php`](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Controller/Component/SessionComponent.php) does exist, at least in the official 2.0.6 repository. Your download/upgrade was probably corrupted. Try adding the file to your server. If you're lucky, that's the only issue; more likely, though, you'll need to reupgrade.

Comment: Hmm. Odd. I'm not seeing it @ https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/tree/master/lib/Cake/Controller

Comment: @bob_cobb It's in the .../Controller/Component directory, not .../Controller.

Comment: Ah my mistake. So I actually DO have this file. Any other ideas why it's giving me this error?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you're looking, but SessionComponent.php does actually exist in the 2.0.x repo:

https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Controller/Component/SessionComponent.php

You may want to re-download your whole /lib section if you're missing files.

Comment: Ah, ok my mistake. I was looking in the wrong directory. When I do open SessionComponent.php, and go to line 32, I get: `class SessionComponent extends Component`. Looks fine to me. Any reason why this is messed up?

Comment: @bob_cobb Have you followed all the recommendations in [the Migration Guide](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-0-migration-guide.html)?

Comment: I've read over the migration guide, but I'm just going with a vanilla installation from scratch removing everything that was there previously (obviously backed up my stuff first).

Comment: @bob_cobb You're going to have to explain a little better.  If you're going with a "vanilla installation", there should be no "removing [things that were] there previously".  If you're trying to use your old 1.3 `/app` files, you're going to have to modify them appropriately to work with 2.0.  Still, double-check Mark's answer and verify that the Component.php file is present in the Controller folder.

Comment: I understand that I need to modify my old `/app` files accordingly, but I simply cleared out my entire web directory, did a fresh install of Cake 2.0 and did the standard installation stuff (changed security salt, made `/tmp` writable, etc). Now I'm met with this weird error even after verifying that Component.php as well as SessionComponent.php exist (Even though originally I was looking in the wrong directory for them).

Comment: @bob_cobb (1)  Do a "bog standard" vanilla 2.0 site and, after verifying that the welcome page works as expected  (2) If the Welcome page loads without a problem, add a simple controller with `$components = array( 'Session' )` and an empty view.  See if that works without modifying anything else...